# Computing quaternions/rotations from 2 points in 3D space

Tags: c++, 3d, rotation, quaternions

I have a kinect application, which sends me the position of the joints as points in 3D space.
The order of the joints is shown in the picture below.
[image]

Now i want to move them in another application which uses a COLLADA coordinate system.
[image]

My thoughts: If i want to rotate the shoulder, i need the Vector (Rshoulder - Relbow) and store it as VX, and then i need to find 2 orthogonal vectors as Y and Z and then compute a quaternion. I may be completly wrong, but this is simply my mindset at the moment..

In a nutshell: how do i successfully compute a rotation, with 2 given points in Y UP system, into a rotation with a Z up system?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the points into your internal coordinate system first, before you do anything else.  Swapping the Y and Z axes is trivial -- just swap the y and z coordinates.  If you want to do everything with matrix chains, you can make a matrix to do this for you:

```
swapYZ_xyz = [ 1 0 0 ]    or,   swapYZ_xyzw = [ 1 0 0 0 ]
             [ 0 0 1 ]                        [ 0 0 1 0 ]
             [ 0 1 0 ]                        [ 0 1 0 0 ]
                                              [ 0 0 0 1 ]
```

Note that this transformation is *not* a rotation:  it is a reflection.  You *need* a reflection here -- there *is* no rotation that can map a left-handed coordinate system onto a right-handed one (as your question requests), while reflections *always* convert between left-handed and right-handed.

This also is why a quaternion representation doesn't make any sense with respect to this overall coordinate conversion: quaternions naturally represent rotations only.

---

Once you have everything in your internal coordinate system, determining the rotation of each joint is a more complicated question (and one I won't solve here in detail, for reasons to follow...)

First off, without additional information, the rotation of each joint is not well-defined.  To see this, suppose you have a set of rotations consistent with a given set of joint locations:  you can then rotate any "bone" between 2 joints to any angle, changing the rotation at both joints without changing the location of the joints.  To eliminate this redundancy, you need to specify additional constraints at some joints -- that is, you need to encode your knowledge about how (e.g.) elbows are allowed to rotate.

Second, once you have resolved the above ambiguities, you will still have cases which are poorly defined -- e.g., if the arms are straight, you actually can't tell how the upper arm is rotated relative to your hands and shoulders.  Any solver will need to deal with this case somehow -- and remember that your data is going to be noisy...

The best overall solution may be to create a mathematical model of your pose, and run a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to integrate the (noisy) input data.  This is a significant undertaking, but it may allow you to deal with noisy data and transient ambiguities in a robust manner.